# Java file corruption uploading via URLConnection

Tags: java, ftp, outputstream, urlconnection

Im not sure why this is happening from time to time but file sizes differ when I upload to a remote ftp server.

Here is how I do this:

```
            URLConnection uc;
            try {
                uc = Init.net.openConnection();
                OutputStream os = uc.getOutputStream();
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("List.jkm");
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int count = 0;
                while((count = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                fis.close();
                os.flush();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Appreciate some hints

Comment: Have you tried adding `os.close()` after your `os.flush()`? Not even sure it would make a difference.

Comment: @Chromos did u even try to search? I did a google search "file size different ftp" and found A LOT of things. That I did not know about.

Comment: Maybe try to use BufferedOutputStream...

Comment: @Eugene I searched but couldnt find results where people tried using URLConnection, which could propably cause problems... I dont know.

Comment: @Chromos this is most probably totally unrelated to java, but the ftp server doing something to the file.

Comment: @Eugene hm most of the time it works just fine. Just sometimes it is corrupted. Dont know if this has somethings to do with file transfer. I thought about a way to check the file-size somehow and if it does not match send the file again